# Solving a non-linear Bernoulli ODE with a power substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have this problem where I have a differential equation on the form

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=ay-\frac{a}{b^2}y^3$$

In this case I am only interested in the positive solution to the equation.

Now since this is a non-linear ODE, it appeared somewhat tedious to solve, but then I recognised that it was infact an equation on the form

$$y'+p(x)y=q(x)y^\beta$$
With $p(x)=-a$ and $q(x)=-a/b^2$,
so using the substitution $u=y^{1-\beta}$ we can write the equation as
$$u'+(1-\beta)py=(1-\beta)q$$
Now for convenience we define $\gamma=(1-\beta)p$ and $\delta=(1-\beta)q$ such that the relationship between $\gamma$ and $\delta$ is

$$\delta=\frac{q}{p}\gamma$$
Since we have reduced the non-linear ODE to a linear ODE, I thought it be wise to throw the laplace transform at it, so we end up with
$$U(s)=\frac{q}{p}\frac{\gamma}{s(s+\gamma)}+\frac{U(0)}{s+\gamma}$$
Taking the inverse laplace transform and using $q/p=1/b^2$ and $\gamma=(1-\beta)p=(1-3)(-a)=2a$, will then give
$$u(t)=\frac{q}{p}(1-e^{-\gamma t})+U(0)e^{-\gamma t}=\frac{1}{b^2}(1-e^{-2at})+c_1e^{-2at}=\frac{e^{2at}-1+b^2c_1}{b^2e^{2at}}$$
Where U(0) is just some constant $c_1$.
Resubbing in $u(t)=y^{1-\beta}=y(t)^{-2}$, inverting and then taking the square root yields
$$y(t)=\frac{|b|e^{at}}{\sqrt{e^{2at}+b^2c_1-1}}$$.

However, when running this equation through Wolfram (y'know just in case...) I get the solution

$$y(t)=\frac{be^{\frac{1}{2}(2at+2b^2c_1)}}{\sqrt{e^{2at+2b^2c_1}-1}}$$
And I am for the lack of better words too daft to see where I done goofed. If anyone immediately sees where it is I would love to have it pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution and WA's are essentially equivalent (but your $c_1$ is not the same as WA's). Too see that, let's rewrite WA's solution as
$$
y(t)=\frac{bCe^{at}}{\sqrt{C^2e^{2at}-1}}=\frac{be^{at}}{\sqrt{e^{2at}-C^{-2}}}, \tag{1}
$$
where $C:=e^{b^2c_1}$. Eq. $(1)$ is equal to your solution if $b>0$ and $C^{-2}=1-b^2c_1$ (that's why your $c_1$ is not the same as WA's).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I see you saying it is "essentially" equivalent. Is the different $c_1$ a case of the equation being solved in a different way, there by the appearance of a different? Just to clear any ambiguity.